# Passing a 2-d array as an element to sklearn.SVM

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I have a single independent variable X where each element is a 2-d array with shape `(20, 431)`. The variable X itself is a 2-d `numpy` array of shape `(200,)`. . How do I pass this to the `sklearn.SVM` object?

Edit: actual dataframe:

```
    Category              Features
0     1        [[-177.08171, -219.89174, -253.55954, -218.560...
1     0        [[-291.89288, -316.40735, -389.8398, -413.6302...
2     1        [[-355.88293, -351.0909, -364.43524, -400.7097.
```

Each element of `Features` is a 20*431 numpy array. I need to use these features to classify the category.

```
x = data.iloc[:, 1].values
y = data.iloc[:, 0].values

x.shape
(200, )

x[0].shape
(20, 431)

y.shape
(200, )
```

Fitting the model after splitting into train and test data:

```
classifier = SVC(kernel = 'rbf', random_state=0)
classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)
```

Error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-203-fdf0fc8db087> in <module>
----> 1 classifier.fit(x_train, y_train)

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\svm\_base.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight)
    160             X, y = self._validate_data(X, y, dtype=np.float64,
    161                                        order='C', accept_sparse='csr',
--> 162                                        accept_large_sparse=False)
    163 
    164         y = self._validate_targets(y)

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in _validate_data(self, X, y, reset, validate_separately, **check_params)
    430                 y = check_array(y, **check_y_params)
    431             else:
--> 432                 X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
    433             out = X, y
    434 

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    801                     ensure_min_samples=ensure_min_samples,
    802                     ensure_min_features=ensure_min_features,
--> 803                     estimator=estimator)
    804     if multi_output:
    805         y = check_array(y, accept_sparse='csr', force_all_finite=True,

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    597                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    598                 else:
--> 599                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    600             except ComplexWarning:
    601                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

~\Anaconda3\envs\LangDetEnv1.0\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order)
     81 
     82     """
---> 83     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
     84 
     85 

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: Where exactly do you get these errors? Can you post entire code and exceptions?

Comment: the actual code is very big, i will make a sample and post it

Comment: You must transfer the matrices (2d-arrays) in arrays of the same length. A good method is to do a pre-processing with a k-means clustering algorithm to generate vectors of length k from each matrix. Now you can use the vectors as an input for the svm.

Comment: All the 2-d arrays are of same shape, so I converted them into 1d arrays using ```ravel()```, but the problem is only a single value is expected from each element, hence I got the same error again.

Comment: @tifi90 the features are actually MFCC features of audio data, so I don't know if generating vectors from k-means will be effective, is there any way i can convert this 2-d matrix itself into an acceptable input?

Comment: Please check this notebook from kaggle on how to process the data: https://www.kaggle.com/anmour/svm-using-mfcc-features